# How to bring the Badge Count in front of the Button in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to show the number of notifications on the top right corner of the button and I am using ViewBadger (an external library : android-viewbadger http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-viewbadger) for it. The problem I am facing right now is the badge is showing at the back of the button like this

[here is the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZbDu.jpg)

But I want to display the badge in front like facebook or any other app

Here is my code

```
package com.daimkhan.badgerview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.readystatesoftware.viewbadger.BadgeView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, button);
    badge.setText("8");
    badge.setTextSize(12);
    badge.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);

    badge.setBadgeMargin(0, 0);

    badge.show();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            badge.hide();
        }
    });

  }
}
```

please help me in this, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think this library is deprecated. You can check new version here: [ActionItemBadge](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge) or try another library: [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger). You can also custom this view.

Comment: I think ShortcutBadger is for App icon and ActionItemBadge is for ActionBar buttons, I am new to android that's why I am week in understanding new libraries. can you provide me any other example to show the badge on any button in any activity? @Hoang Nguyen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this before showing the badge

```
ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(badge, 10);
```

This changes the elevation of the view with respect to Z-axis.

The official documentation says

```
setTranslationZ
void setTranslationZ (View view, float translationZ)
Sets the depth location of this view relative to its elevation.
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: finally i got the solution for the problem, however i dropped this library before and took a new route to show the number of notifications in the button text. i know the approach is not good but for the time being it helped me and now after getting the exact solution, i am going to add it in the next update. thank you soo much @AIK :)

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me, with the same code you provided;

try to use this as your layout file(may be the problem is in your layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i use the same layout and the same code (copy/paste) and the same lib (http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-viewbadger) but i do not have this problem.

in this case i think it is a problem in the manifest, may be the AppTheme or the used API.

try to use this as your application theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and this option in the gradle if you're using Android Studio :
`compileSdkVersion 22 ,
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1 ,
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'`
to confirm that we're using the same configuration  
along with the same code.

Comment: I tried what you said but the problem is still there

Answer (score -1):

Heads up, the button will auto adjust its translationZ value each time it's clicked, thanks to stateListAnimator (This exists, at least in part, to make sure buttons come to the front when they are clicked... this is not always desirable). For full Z order control over views when one or all of them are buttons, turn off stateListAnimator in xml with android:stateListAnimator="@null"

[image]